# Adjust playback speed of videos in a browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, flash, playback

There is a program at [enounce.com](http://www.enounce.com/)  that it will increase the play speed of a video in a browser. I think that 95% of videos on the internet run on flash therefore this tool can be useful. I am wondering how that program was created. Maybe they modify the html source in the browser? perhaps it looks for the swf video playing on your browser and it injects some JavaScript on that html element to increase the speed. I been researching on Google and I think it is possible to alter the playback speed of a video with JavaScript. If it is not modifying the html page then it will be nice to at least know how this can be achieved. Also if a video plays on your browser it has to be saved somewhere in your computer I believe. That's why you can seek back and forth once the video finished downloading. why is it that it is almost impossible to find it and the only way of getting that video will be by capturing the packages with a package sniffer? anyways that is not my question I am just really curious on how that program achieves doing what it does. it speeds up everything even Pandora songs.

Answer (score 0):

MySpeed seems to intercept the media stream coming from the server into the Flash player that sits in your browser. It changes the speed on the fly, and sends the result to the Flash player.

PS: If you need to control the playing speed of your own videos I recommend looking into the VLC Browser Plug-in, or the QuickTime player, which also has very good speed control features (from Javascript). Or you could use the HTML5 <video> tag.

Afaik, Flash-based players like Longtail/JWPlayer and Nonverbla don't have very good support for this.